# why operator '=' can not match?

Tags: c++

I constantly got compilation error:

> no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘bObj1 =
>   Balance::operator+(Balance&)(((Balance&)(& bObj2)))’

Could you someone help to point out the reason?
Thanks in advance.

code:

```
class Balance
{
public:
    Balance (int b = 0) {balance = b;};
    Balance (Balance &);

    Balance & operator= (Balance &);
    Balance operator+ (Balance &);

    int get() {return balance;};
    void set(int b) {balance = b;};

private:
    int balance;
};

Balance & Balance::operator=(Balance &copy)
{
    balance = copy.get();
    return *this;
}

Balance Balance::operator+ (Balance &rig)
{
    Balance add;
    add.set(this->get() + rig.get());
    return add;
}

int main()
{
    Balance bObj1, bObj2(100);
    bObj1 = bObj2;
    bObj1 = bObj1 + bObj2; // This line cause the error.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have issues when using operator overrides with non-const references.  Change your functions to const:

```
Balance & operator= (const Balance &);
Balance operator+ (const Balance &) const;

int get() const { return balance; }
```

When the `+` operator is applied, the result is an *rvalue*, which is immutable.  Because your `=` could not accept an `rvalue` reference (because it was not const), the compiler was unable to match the operator.

Above, I've made your functions rvalue-friendly.  The `=` operator will accept an rvalue.  The `+` operator also accepts an rvalue and is `const` because it doesn't modify the object.  Because it is const, I've made the `get` function const too.

Comment: Oh, I missed one.  Your copy constructor should also take a const-reference: `Balance (const Balance &)`

Comment: Or create a move assignment constructor

Answer (score 2):

Your assigment operator is wrong. You can safety remove it, because implicit operator is enough for you simple class.
Read [When do I need to write an assignment operator?](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) for more details.

```
class Balance
{
public:
  Balance (int b = 0) {balance = b;};
  Balance operator+ (const Balance &);

  int get() const {return balance;};
  void set(int b) {balance = b;};

private:
  int balance;
};

Balance Balance::operator+ (const Balance &rig)
{
  Balance add;
  add.set(this->get() + rig.get());
  return add;
}
```